How to get Laravel Fortify errors in the response
I am trying to migrate from a own auth provider to the Fortify auth provider from laravel (11). But I am experiencing issues with the responses from fortify when logging in or any messages that would return.
My FortifyServiceProvider:
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Actions\Fortify\CreateNewUser;
use App\Actions\Fortify\ResetUserPassword;
use App\Actions\Fortify\UpdateUserPassword;
use App\Actions\Fortify\UpdateUserProfileInformation;
use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiting\Limit;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Laravel\Fortify\Fortify;

class FortifyServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register() {}

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Fortify::createUsersUsing(CreateNewUser::class);
        Fortify::updateUserProfileInformationUsing(UpdateUserProfileInformation::class);
        Fortify::updateUserPasswordsUsing(UpdateUserPassword::class);
        Fortify::resetUserPasswordsUsing(ResetUserPassword::class);

        RateLimiter::for('login', function(Request $request) {
            $throttleKey = strtolower($request->input(Fortify::username())) . '|' . $request->ip();

            return Limit::perMinute(5)->by($throttleKey);
        });
        
        Fortify::loginView(function() {
            return view('auth.login');
        });

        Fortify::requestPasswordResetLinkView(function() {
            return view('auth.forgot-password');
        });

        Fortify::resetPasswordView(function($request) {
            return view('auth.reset-password', ['request' => $request]);
        });
    }
}

In my login blade I tried serveral things to get the errors (when I fill in my password incorrectly, but nothing worked:
@php
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
@endphp

@extends('layouts.master-without-nav')

@section('title')
  {{ __('translation.Login') }}
@endsection

@section('body')
  <body>
@endsection
@section('content')
  <div class="account-pages my-5 pt-sm-5">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-6 col-xl-5">
          <div class="card overflow-hidden">
            <div class="bg-primary bg-soft">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-7">
                  <div class="text-primary p-4">
                    <h5 class="text-primary">{{ __('translation.Welcome_Back') }} !</h5>
                    <p>{{ __('translation.Sign_in_to_continue_to') }} {{ config('app.name') }}.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-5 align-self-end">
                  <img src="{{ URL::asset('/assets/images/profile-img.png') }}" alt="{{ config('app.name') }}" class="img-fluid">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body pt-0">
              @if (session('status'))
                <div class="mb-4 font-medium text-sm text-green-600">{{ session('status') }}</div>
              @endif
              @if ($errors->any())
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                  <ul>
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                      <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                  </ul>
                </div>
              @endif
              <div class="auth-logo">
                <div class="auth-logo-light logo-light">
                  <div class="avatar-md profile-user-wid mb-4">
                    <a href="{{ route('home') }}">
                      <span class="avatar-title rounded-circle bg-light">
                        <img src="{{ URL::asset('/assets/images/logo-light.svg') }}" alt="{{ config('app.name') }}" class="" height="30">
                      </span>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="auth-logo-dark logo-dark">
                  <div class="avatar-md profile-user-wid mb-4">
                    <a href="{{ route('home') }}">
                      <span class="avatar-title rounded-circle bg-light">
                        <img src="{{ URL::asset('/assets/images/black-logo.png') }}" alt="{{ config('app.name') }}" class="" height="30">
                      </span>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="p-2">
                <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                  @csrf

                  @if ($errors->any())
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                      <ul>
                        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                          <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                        @endforeach
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  @endif

                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="username" class="form-label">{{ __('translation.Email') }}</label>
                    <input
                      name="email"
                      type="email"
                      class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror"
                      value="{{ old('email') }}"
                      id="username"
                      placeholder="{{ __('translation.Enter_Email') }}"
                      autocomplete="email"
                      autofocus>
                    @error('email')
                      <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                      </span>
                    @enderror
                  </div>

                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <label class="form-label">{{ __('translation.Password') }}</label>
                      <div class="input-group auth-pass-inputgroup @error('password') is-invalid @enderror">
                        <input
                          type="password"
                          name="password"
                          class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror"
                          id="userpassword"
                          placeholder="{{ __('translation.Enter_Password') }}"
                          aria-label="Password"
                          aria-describedby="password-addon">
                          <button class="btn btn-light " type="button" id="password-addon">
                            <i class="mdi mdi-eye-outline"></i>
                          </button>
                          @error('password')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                              <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                          @enderror
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      @if ($errors->any())
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                          <ul>
                            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                              <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                            @endforeach
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                      @endif

                      @if (session('error'))
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ session('error') }}</div>
                      @endif
                      <div class="form-check">
                        <input
                          class="form-check-input"
                          type="checkbox"
                          id="remember"
                          {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">{{ __('translation.Remember_me') }}</label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="mt-3 d-grid">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">{{ __('translation.Log_In') }}</button>
                      </div>

                      <div class="mt-4 text-center">
                        @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                          <a href="{{ route('password.request') }}" class="text-muted">
                            <i class="mdi mdi-lock me-1"></i> {{ __('translation.Forgot_your_password') }}
                          </a>
                        @endif
                      </div>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="mt-5 text-center">
                <div>
                  <p>©
                    <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script> Interactive X-Wall B.V.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- end account-pages -->
@endsection

The statuscode of the login is always 302 (I dont know if this is correct for Fortify, couldnt find any documentation for it).
I tried debugging the serviceprovider, tried alll laravel methods to catch the errors. I personally think its about the request but I dont know where to look.
